# Handle websocketpp connection path

Tags: c++, c++11, websocket, boost-asio, websocket++

I'm really newbie in websocketpp. Can you tell me please, how can i get websocket connection path on new connection in my server? I mean i need to get the part of this:

```
ws://localhost:8080/addr1    ------> get addr1
ws://localhost:8080/addr2    ------> get addr2
ws://localhost:8080/etc      ------> get etc
```

I'm using now an example from this link: http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/storing-connection-specificsession-information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, i found soultion by myself :) You should use following code for that purpose:

```
server::connection_ptr con = s.get_con_from_hdl(hdl);
std::string path = con->get_resource();
```